# c# converting PDF to Tif

Tags: c#, ocr

i was using ghostscript to convert PDF's to Tif with C$ class wrapper and then was using OCR tessnet2 to read the content of the image file but the tif images are pretty much unreadable, the image is pretty faded and doesnt look right and the OCR engine fails to read anything. Is there any open source or library that will cost me few bucks out there that can convert PDFs to TIf in good quality? or any open source OCR engine that read PDF's because tessnet2 cannot read PDF's.

Comment: Is the original PDF a collection of pictures?  Because if it isn't, I think you're going about this the wrong way.  Ordinary PDF's already contain the text you need; your approach should be to extract the text out of the PDF directly, rather than trying to OCR it out of a picture of the PDF.

Comment: How long is a piece of string ? As usual with these questions it is imposible to know what is going on until we can see the pdf file in question.

Comment: In this case it sounds like a poor quality scanned image that has been converted to a pdf. It may need need some image preprocessing before using OCR like deskew, despeckle, edge enhancement, thresholding. OCR output quality is directly related to input quality. Garbage in = Garbage out. Improving the image quality will yield the best results. Many image based PDF's don't have a hidden text layer but many do have poor OCR data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to change properties of imageMagicNET class output format to png16m and DPI so the images generated are high quality and readable for the OCR engine

Answer (score 1):

As DaNet said, I'm not sure if there is any an open source DLL or a free way to do that. We use a third-party toolkit named leadtools that gives us very good results when OCR PDF documents. You can use it to do some processing on the image (i.e. binarize it, remove the unwanted dots from the image, convert it to 1-bit black & white, save it as TIF image, etc), and then pass it to their OCR engine.
I know that they have an online demo, you can try it. Here is the link for the demo:
http://demo.leadtools.com/OnlineRecognitionDemo

If the results match your requirements, you can check this tutorial:
[Scanning to Searchable PDF](http://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v175/dh/to/leadtools.topics.forms.ocr~fo.topics.ocrtutorialscanningtosearchablepdf.html)

Answer (score 0):

I not sure about a opensource OCR, but if you play with the resolution output of ghostscript generated tiff you shouldn't have a problem.

Tried to add -r150 to the "string args" of the ghostscript wrapper to changes the resolution and hopefully a decent size megabyte file!

Comment: i had to change properties of imageMagicNET class output format to png16m and DPI so the images generated are high quality and readable for the OCR engine

Comment: Good to know when I am trying OCR!